# Gradle dependency causing error "Invalid Magic Number"

Tags: android, git, gradle, proguard, magic-numbers

I have a project on GitHub that I work on both in the office at home. For about 2 months it was working fine on both machines. Then two weeks ago, it stopped running on my home PC, but **still works fine on my work PC**.

This is the error I get:

> :app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents'.
>     java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\dev\gitRepo\app\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\allclasses.jar] (Can't process class [__MACOSX/com/stripe/android/._BuildConfig.class] (Invalid magic number [51607] in class))
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

The `stripe` package that is giving me errors is a 3rd party library [that you can find here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android). I list it as a dependency in my build.gradle file exactly as they say to.

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

I have commented out all code pertaining the `stripe` and the app runs completely fine, so I do know it has something to do with how I am handling that package.

Unfortunately I don't remember exactly what I had done to make this stop working. I do think that the week before this happened I upgraded Android Studio, and spent a considerable amount of time messing with `ProGuard` configurations.

**What I have tried:**

- Working on the `master` branch where no `ProGuard` changes have been made.
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Android Studio
- Re-cloning the git repo
- Installing API 17 (stripe for eclipse requires this. Not Studio but I gave it a shot).
- Contacting stripe customer support but they had no clue.
- [This stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798090/java-io-ioexception-cant-process-class-when-running-proguard-in-maven-build-of). However, there is no Mac computer that has touched the project nor have I personally zipped anything related to `stripe`.
- [From here](http://slightlyrandombrokenthoughts.blogspot.com/2010/03/reverse-engineering-java-class-magic.html), converted the magic number from Hex to ASCII. The result was **Q`** which I do not recognize.

I think it may have something to do with something I did for ProGuard, but I don't understand how. I'm on a completely different branch than any Proguard work, with a clean AndroidStudio install, with a clean repository clone, and the project still works fine when I'm in the office.

**EDIT**

I am running this on the `debug` BuildType. These are my 3 gradle files. The first is for the entire Project, the second is for the Application Module, and the third is for a local android library Module.

**Project `build.gradle`**:
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
            classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        }
    }

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{ url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
}
```

**Android Application Module `build.gradle`**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.android"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'false'
        }
        adhoc {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'enableCrashlytics', 'true'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':localLibrary')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.0.1'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Local Android Library Module `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5'

}
```

Comment: Invalid magic number indicates problems around java-version

Comment: @ligi do you mean the Java version of the machine I'm using?

Comment: I'd avoid using the `+` in the dependency - specify the full version number for `stripe-android` instead.  Then you can try different versions to see if one is the problem. Same goes for `io.fabric.tools:gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably related to the version of Java that you are running. I had a similar problem and discovered that Java 8 was used for the build. When I changed to Java 7, this build problem was fixed.

In Android Studio go to

```
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location
```

The `JDK Location` should be Java 1.7.x (Java 7)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah verify both machines have the same Java version, and indeed the same version of Android Studio. The only other thing I can think of is that maybe Stripe is using the build tools bundled with AS to build your apk, and the ones you have installed by default differ slightly and are missing something - [see this post I made on a similar problem I had](https://medium.com/@Wingnut/installing-android-studio-and-an-ensuing-rabbit-hole-ac3d9a0d3115#.g5r3vge9d).

Comment: I haven't been able to test this yet, but the bounty is expiring so I'm giving it to you. I'll check this weekend on my home PC.